# Advice for voting form with php and bitrix

Tags: php, html, vote, bitrix

Currently working with Bitrix CMS and need to make vote for users from specific group. With knowing id of group i made a form with bunch of radio buttons inside. When someone vote, result shoud be writen in file (or database) and page with "Thank you for voting!" should be displayed.
My question is **what is the best way to do it?**
I tried a few different ways:
1) [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php--net-57), not working
2) two another web tutorials, can link if you ask me
3) Voting form from bitrix, but for that module of the system should be change, and that not advised.

Below is page with vote itself, but "poll.php" makes me confused because of not knowing right way to do it. So good advice would be really appreciated.

p.s. you can ignore 'Bitrix' part, most important is php

```html
/*get users from group in array*/
<?$arUsers = CGroup::GetGroupUser(20);
$iCountUsers = 0;
$arUsersbyGroupID = array();
foreach($arUsers as $arUser) {
 $arUserbyID = CUser::GetByID($arUser);
 $rsUserbyID = $arUserbyID -> Fetch();
 $arUsersbyGroupID[] = $rsUserbyID; }
 $iCountUsers++;?>

<div class="wrapper">
      <div id="poll-container">
       <form class="grid" action="poll.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
         /*for each create element with radio button*/
  <?$iVoteCount = 0;
  $allopt = array();
  foreach($arUsersbyGroupID as $Vote) {
  $photo = $Vote["PERSONAL_PHOTO"];
   if (!empty($photo)) {
   $name = "{$Vote["NAME"]} {$Vote["LAST_NAME"]}";?>
        <div class="cell">
   <div class="cell_img"><?echo CFile::ShowImage($photo)?></div>
            <div class="cell_caption">
                    <input type="radio" value="<?=$iVoteCount?>" name="vote" onclick="getVote(this.value)" />
                    <label for='opt<?=$iVoteCount?>'><?echo $name?></label>
            </div>
        </div>
  $iVoteCount++;
}
  } ?>
        <div id="sub"><input type="submit" value="Vote" /></div>
    </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you could use standard component of bitrix bitrix:voting.current

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write your fully custom solution for creating polls. In Bitrix Framework we have a module called - `vote`

With supply of this module you can create standard polls or if they are not fit to your tasks - you can customize them, but you should not be writing all these code from scratch.

For basic polls configuration you can read official online courses (in Russian) - http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=41&LESSON_ID=2859

Answer (score 0):

Use bitrix api to transfer your array data using $_POST or $_REQUEST global varibles binding them to your custom form name[] . Just add bitrix api code on after submit event. Voting results may be pasted into the custom lead fields that should be previously created in BX manually. Check out this example. It was fully workable and tested.

```
   <?php
    $queryUrl ='';
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $ip;
     $queryData = http_build_query($basebitrix24 = array(
     'fields' => array(
     "TITLE" =>'one',
     "NAME" => 'two',
     "LAST_NAME" => $leadData['question_one'],
     "STATUS_ID" => "NEW",
     "OPENED" => "Y",

    "UF_CRM_1491235024" => $leadData['question_second'], 
    "UF_CRM_1491235124" =>   $leadDataQ1[$answer],
    "UF_CRM_1491235376" =>  $leadData['question_third'], 
     "ASSIGNED_BY_ID" => 16,
    'SOURCE_ID' => $i,
     "PHONE" => array(array("VALUE" => $_REQUEST['phone'], "VALUE_TYPE" => "WORK" )),
     "EMAIL" => array(array("VALUE" => $_REQUEST['email'], "VALUE_TYPE" => "WORK" )),
     ),
     'params' => array("REGISTER_SONET_EVENT" => "Y")
     )); 
     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
     CURLOPT_POST => 1,
     CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
     CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
     ));
     $result = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    ?>
```

The requests are not about voting but there is no very much trouble to use same method for any custom form too. Form code in example purposes.

```
    if (isset($_POST['s_submit'])) {
        @$email = strtolower(trim($_POST['email']));
        @$name = trim($_POST['name']);

        if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) != 0) {
            if (@isset($email) && @$email != '') {
                $line = check_record_exist($removelist, $email, $form_type);
                if ($line) {
                    $line--;
                    delete_line_from_file($removelist, $line);
                }
                if (!check_record_exist($addlist, $email, $form_type)) {
                    add_record($addlist, $email, $name);
                    $sm_res = 1;
                } else {
                    $sm_res = 3;
                }
            } else
                echo '<font color="#FF0000">Please enter e-mail address</font>';
        }
    }

    if (isset($sm_res)) {
        switch ($sm_res) {
            case '1': echo '<b>You have successfully subscribed</b>';
                break;
            case '2': echo '<b>You have successfully unsubscribed</b>';
                break;
            case '3': echo '<b>You are already subscribed</b>';
                break;
            case '4': echo '<b>You are already unsubscribed</b>';
                break;
        }
        unset($sm_res);
    } else {
    <form name="contactform"  id="sky-form" method="post" action="">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="sky-form epochta"> 
              <section class="col col-6"  >
                 <label class="input"><i class="icon-append icon-envelope-alt"></i> <h3>EMAIL </h3><input type="email" name="email" value="<?$_REQUEST['email']?>">      </label>
                                        </section>
                                        <?php if ($form_type != 1) { ?>
                                        <section class="col col-6">

                   <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-user"></i><h3>NAME<h3> <input type="text" name="name" size="15" value="<?php echo @trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['name'])); ?>">
                        </label>
              </section>
                                          <?php } ?>
        <section class="col col-12"  >

                            <input type="hidden" name="saved" value="yes">

                    <input type="submit" class="subbutton"  name="submit" value="">        

                                <td align="center" colspan="2"><a href="http://www.epochta.ru/products/subscription/" target="_blank"><font face="Verdana" size="-2">ePochta Subscription Manager</font></a>

          </section>

          </div>
          </div>
                </fieldset>
          </form>
    ?>
```